# Can an enum be reduced to its bit size in C++?

Tags: c++

Given the following - can I get `sizeof(A)` to be `1`? Right now I'm getting `8`, but I'd like `A` to be equal in layout to `Z` - as the enum only has one bit of data.

```
enum BOOL { x , y};

struct A {
    BOOL b : 1;
    unsigned char c : 7;
};
struct Z {
    unsigned char r : 1;
    unsigned char c : 7;
};

int main()
{

    A b;
    b.b = x;
    std::cout << b.b  << "," << sizeof(A) << ","<< sizeof(Z) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `enum BOOL { x , y};` <-- why not just use a `bool`? Or a bitfield, if you want just 1 bit of storage.

Comment: Try using *alignas* keyword. If it doesn't work, then the easiest method would be to declare the char and split it internally.

Comment: Imagine it says enum TRIBOOL as {x,y,z} if it makes you happy and substitute 2/6.

Comment: _"if it makes you happy"_ Steady...

Comment: @JesperJuhl the names in the example are silly, and fail to demonstrate the usefulness of enum instead of a bool. Once you give sensible names, it becomes clear how the enum can be superior to bool. For example: `enum should_throw : bool {no_throw, yes_throw};`, and compare these calls `function(argument, no_throw)`, `function(argument, false)`. Which one is clear about the meaning of the second argument?

Comment: You can find out the underlying type by using ```std::underlying_type<BOOL>::type;```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that `BOOL` will use an `int` as the underlying type by default.  Since it uses an `int`, it is padding the struct out to have a size of `8` as that will keep the `int` part of the struct nicely aligned.

What you can do though is specify that you don't want an `int`, but instead want an `unsigned char` so that it can pack both bitfields in a single member.  This isn't guaranteed, but makes it much more likely to happen.  Using

```
enum BOOL : unsigned char { x , y};
```

makes `A` have a sizeof `1` in GCC, Clang and MSVC

Comment: Should this not be an ```enum class```?

Comment: @Bart It does not need to be.  In C++11 we got the ability to set the type,and to make it a "class"

Comment: A I always read this as if setting the type was an option for the enum class. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use bool as the underlying type of the enum:

```
enum BOOL : bool { x , y};
```

Given this, *on my system*, `sizeof(A)` is 1. I don't think that is guaranteed given that much of bit field structure is implementation defined, and `bool` itself is technically not guaranteed to have size 1.

Using `unsigned char` is another alternative, which may be handled better with the adjacent `unsigned char` bitfield member on some implementations. Unfortunately though, GCC for example warns `warning: 'A::b' is too small to hold all values of 'enum BOOL'` which is technically a false positive, since one bit is sufficient to represent 0 and 1.